# JavaScript jQuery delay oninput

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, ajax

I have a html table which gets its values from a database through jQuery Ajax.
Something like this

```
<div id="tableId"></div>
```

Than the java script:

```
function showUser(rowsToShow) {
  request = $.get("showTableFunction.php", {
    q: rowsToShow
  });

  request.done(function(response, textStatus, jqXHR) {
    $("#tableId").html(response);
  });

  request.fail(function(jqXHR, textStatus, errorThrown) {
    console.log("The following error occurred: " + textStatus, errorThrown);
  });
}
```

The table has a oninput function which updated the database every time the user changes the value of one of the cells.

```
function updateCell(data) {
  var cellId= data.id;
  var editValue = $(data).text();

  requestEdit = $.post("editCellFunction.php", {
    cellId: cellId,
    editValue: editValue,
  });

  requestEdit.done(function(response, textStatus, jqXHR) {
    console.log(textStatus);
    });

  requestEdit.fail(function(jqXHR, textStatus, errorThrown) {
    console.log("The following error occurred: " + textStatus, errorThrown);
  });

}
```

However this causes a major load on the website.
So I want to add a delay that only if there was no new input for lets say 5 seconds it will execute the Ajax request

Would greatly appreciate it sometime can help with this.

Comment: Javascript's `setTimeout( functionToCallAfterTimeout, timeoutInMs )` should work for u...

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I actually just implemented something really similar. Basically, you want to set a timer via `setTimeout` that starts *and resets* when you receive an input.

```js
const input = document.getElementById('input');
const output = document.getElementById('output');
let timer = null;

function updateDatabase() {
  // your code here, but for this example, I'll just change some text.
  output.textContent = input.value;
}

function restartTimer() {
  clearTimeout(timer);
  timer = setTimeout(updateDatabase, 300);
}

input.addEventListener('input', restartTimer);
```

```html
<input type="text" id="input">

<p>Sent:</p>
<p id="output"></p>
```