# Autosaving textarea field in jQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, ajax

I would like to request some help in saving data from a "notepad" using Ajax. The notepad in my case is a simple textarea for which we can capture an onchange event.

HTML

```
<textarea id="notepad"></textarea>
```

jQuery

```
$('#notepad').on('change paste keyup', function(event) {

    var formData = $(this).serialize();

    $.ajax({
        url: url,
        type: 'POST',
        data: formData,
        success: function(data, status) {
            console.log('Something worked');
        },
        error: function(xhr, desc, err) {
            console.log('Something went wrong');
        }
    });
}
```

The above code works perfect for what I need to do. However, in practice I found that the above code is not perfect for this scenario, since a lot of content would go through this `textarea` having an ajax call for **every** keyup / change is a lot of Ajax and MySQL calls.

I wanted help in figuring out how I could somehow trigger the Ajax call only after the change in text is completed. My first instinct was to add a delay to the ajax call, but that would still mean many many ajax calls after a set number of time.

Is there any way for me to completely hold of Ajax calls until the very end? That is maybe 5 seconds after the user has finished adding content to the textarea?

**Note:** Adding a submit button is not an option sadly.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [JavaScript jQuery delay oninput](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59204338/javascript-jquery-delay-oninput)

Comment: @A.Meshu thank you for that. Can't believe it was actually that simple.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try changing which events you're listening for via jQuery. 'change paste keyup' are all different events. Try taking 'keyup' out and leave the other two.

That's the simplest answer.

Another more complicated option is to add a timer that delays the ajax until a certain amount of time has passed.

```
$('#notepad').on('change paste keyup', function(event) {
  var formData = $(this).serialize();
  setTimeout(function(){

    $.ajax({
      url: url,
      type: 'POST',
      data: formData,
      success: function(data, status) {
          console.log('Something worked');
      },
      error: function(xhr, desc, err) {
          console.log('Something went wrong');
      }
    });
  }, 3000);
}
```

Two notes: I left the formData variable outside the timeout because "this" will not function the same inside an anonymous function. (Another option would be to save "this" to a different variable, then serialize your form data inside the timeout.)

```
var thisForm = $(this)
setTimeout(function(){
  var formData = thisForm.serialize()
```

Finally, the "3000" is the time in MS after the event fires that the timeout will take to trigger.

Also--use const or let instead of var. (See https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/const and https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/let)

Comment: Regardless of the events. What I am trying to achieve is to delay the Ajax call until the user is done with typing into the field. This means that ajax should only trigger once after a certain amount of time.

Comment: OK. I'll modify my answer to include another option.

Comment: And if A.Meshu's answer above works better for you, that's fine. I don't use jQuery much, so I probably shouldn't have stuck my nose in here. :P